# I'm trying to change my background with python but its just becoming a black screen

Tags: python, ctypes, index-error

I want it to chose a random `.png` from a file and make it the background of my computer. It worked without the random file stuff, but I only get a black screen or an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

```
import ctypes
import glob, random

file_path_type = ["./backgrounds/*.png"]
images = glob.glob(random.choice(file_path_type))
random_image = random.choice(images)
print(random_image)


def changeBG(random_image):
    SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
    ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(20, 0, random_image, 2)
    return;


changeBG(random_image)
```

I dont really know what to do. I have tried looking it up but I cannot find anything.

Comment: You have the `glob.glob` and `random.choice` calls reversed.  You need to do the glob FIRST, then take a random choice from that.  Then you can skip the second call to `random.choice`.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but could you show me what you mean by that?

Comment: I'm just saying the `random.choice` call inside `glob.glob` is silly.  The list contains one item, so `choice` will always return that item.  The REAL problem here is likely that you are specifying a relative file path.  The system doesn't know where you are.  Try doing `random_image = os.abspath(random_image)`.